How to Handle Google Play Developer Account Restriction Due to Identity Verification Issues?
Hello Developers,
I'm facing an issue with my Google Play Developer account being restricted due to identity verification problems. Here's a summary of the situation:
I received a notification from Google Play requiring me to verify my identity.
I tried to verify my identity using my phone number, but consistently received an error message instructing me to try again later.
After contacting Google Play support, I was advised to use another phone number. I tried two other numbers from my country, but the error persisted. Finally, I used a US number, which I was eventually able to verify. Despite this, my account was restricted
I received an email stating:
**"You must accurately provide your developer account information, including the following details:
Legal name and address
Contact email address and phone number
Developer email address and phone number shown on Google Play where applicable."**
I made all the indicated corrections. My payment profile information and Play Console account details were updated and contain the same information, yet the account remains restricted.
I submitted an appeal explaining the error and also requested a chat in Spanish, but the response did not address this.
This was the reply I received:
**"Thanks for contacting the Google Play team.
As much as I'd like to help, I’m not able to provide any more information. Unfortunately, we are unable to verify the documents you provided and are unable to grant your appeal.
If you are located in the EU, you may have additional redress options. Learn more about those potential options in the EU Out-of-Court Dispute Resolution Help Center. Routing ID: ZLFS
Thanks again for your understanding."**
I understand the importance of maintaining accurate information and would like to resolve this issue promptly. However, the responses from Google support have been unhelpful, and I'm not sure what more I can do to regain full access to my developer account. I would appreciate your recommendations on how to proceed to solve this issue. the Question is:
How should I proceed to resolve this issue?

For complete verification, the details in your Play Console account must match the details in Google Pay and the documents you provided for verification. If any detail is misspelled or does not match, then the account cannot be verified.
Verifying your Play Console account:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/14177239?hl=en
